# using boost shared pointer in std::string to assign a variable

Tags: c++

Hello i am new to c++ ,

I am trying to use shared pointer on a string.

```
class Test{
private:
void test(std::string* str);
boost::shared_ptr<std::string> sample;
};

void Test::test(std::string* str) {

 sample.reset(str); //This is not working.
}
```

can any one tell me what is wrong?

Comment: Doesn't your compiler tell you what's wrong?

Comment: Not your question but using a shared_ptr on a string seems like overkill. Any reason you have for not just using a plain string, `std::string sample;`? Apart from anything else `std::string` may well be implemented using reference counting anyway, in which case `boost::shared_ptr<std::string>` is just a waste.

Comment: How is it not working? How is the `str` argument created by the caller?

Comment: I cannot imagine _any_ scenario where `std::shared_ptr<std::string>` would be appropriate.  `std::string` is a value oriented class, and should never be allocated dynamically.

Answer (score 2):

First you declare

```
void test();
```

Then you implement

```
void Test::test(std::string* str) {
```

This is not supposed to work

Comment: ok then please also add the compiler error message to your question